# Having two radio buttons have the same ID with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

How is there a way to make a radio button set have same IDs?

Reason I ask is that i'm making a form in which radio buttons are used, but every question is required. Using JS, I made it so that works.

Here is my code:

```
<form>                
            <label>First name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="fname"> <br><br>
            <label>Last name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="lname"> <br><br>
            <label>Email address:</label>
            <input type="text" id="email"> <br><br>
            <label>Age</label>
            <input type="text" id="age"> <br><br>
            <label>Gender:</label><br>
            <!-- radio button *help* -->
            <input type="radio"> Male<br>
            <input type="radio"> Female<br>
            <input type="radio"> Other <br><br>
            <!-- radio button *help* -->
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
            <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
        </form>
```

JS:

```
var $ = function ( id ) { return document.getElementById( id ); }



            var check = function()
            {

                var first = $("fname").value;
                var last = $("lname").value;
                var email = $("email").value;
                var comments = $("comments").value;
                var errors = "";

                if ( first == "" )
                    errors += "You must enter a first name \n";
                if ( last == "" )
                    errors += "You must enter a last name \n";
                if ( email == "" )
                    errors += "You must enter an email address \n";

                if ( errors == "" )
                    alert( "Thank you" );
                else
                    alert( errors );
            }

            window.onload = function()
            {
                $("submit").onclick = check;
            }
```

Please note that I've started JS about 2 weeks ago, so any help is useful!

Thanks!

Comment: You should never have two elements with the same ID. IDs are supposed to be unique.

Comment: You shouldn't use the same `ID` multiple times. `ID`'s are supposed to be unique. To target a group of elements you should use a `class` name.

Answer (score 0):

An ID in HTML needs to be unique. You could add `required` to your radio elements so that atleast one with the same name group needs to be selected.

```html
<form>
<input type="radio" name="gender" required /> Male<br />
<input type="radio" name="gender" required /> Female<br />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```